# Error in tensorflow.js multiple regression sgd minimize

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorflow.js

this is my first post. I am facing an error with fitting a curve in tensorflow.js which I can't seem to fix. I have spent two days on it so far. Since tensorflow.js is pretty new, there's not a whole lot of answers to this sort of question out there, so I'm sure many people are interested in this. I have tried to replicate the example from the tensorflow.js project's website:

https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/fit-curve.html .

The difference is that I am using multiple predictors to predict an outcome variable. I have 20 prices, and I am using the previous 4 prices to predict the fifth one. So I start out with price number 5 and go up to price number 20 where price 5 is predicted by price 1 to 4 and so forth in a weighted time-series prediction model. I am using a multiple linear regression framework where I set up 4 random parameters (one weight for each of the four previous prices). My goal is to train the variable to minimize my loss function (using minimum least square criterion). I have tried following the example from the link as closely as possible. Whenever I run my code I get:

Error: The f passed in variableGrads(f) must be a function

which is generated by the call of .minimize in line 59 (right before return in the train function at the end). Basicially what I'm doing is fit a linear regression which could be more easily done in R but we aim at very large data sets and more complex machine learning procedures. I'm sure this is interesting to a lot of other people who are getting started woth tensorflow.js.

here's my code with some comments:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');

require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

module.exports = function tensorFlow() {
//the trainable variable with initial random numbers
let lag = tf.variable(tf.tensor([Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()], [4])); 

//20 observed prices
let priceData = [21.00397, 21.29068, 22.80492, 23.40646, 24.06598, 23.89722, 25.40211, 24.63436, 25.83449, 26.44832, 26.25194, 27.34009, 27.90455, 27.14175, 28.12549, 29.99411, 30.43631, 30.39753, 30.16104, 31.14931]; 

//the prices from price 5 on that are to be predicted
let toBePredictedList = [24.06598, 23.89722, 25.40211, 24.63436, 25.83449, 26.44832, 26.25194, 27.34009, 27.90455, 27.14175, 28.12549, 29.99411, 30.43631, 30.39753, 30.16104, 31.14931];

//set up tensor of labels to compare predictions with
let toBePredicted = tf.tensor(toBePredictedList, [16]);

//a list of predictors with 16 rows and four columns for 16 predictions to be made using 4 previous prices each
let predictorsList = [];

for (let predictorIndex = 0; predictorIndex < 16; predictorIndex++) {
    for (let predictionsIndex = 0; predictionsIndex < 4; predictionsIndex++) {
        predictorsList.push(priceData[predictorIndex + predictionsIndex]);
    }
}

//make it a tensor
let predictors = tf.tensor(predictorsList, [16, 4]);

//predict multiplies all predictors in all lines with the parameters from lag to be trained and adds up the four elements to generate an estimate of the fifth price
function predict(predictors) {
    function modelMaker() {
        let modelList = [];

        for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 16; rowIndex++) {
            let prediction = 0;

            for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < 4; colIndex++) {
                prediction += lag.get(colIndex) * predictors.get(rowIndex, colIndex);
                console.log({prediction});
            }
            modelList.push(prediction);
        }
        return tf.tensor(modelList, [16]);
    }

    return tf.tidy(modelMaker);
}

//means square error of my prediction when compared to actual outcome price
function loss(predictions, toBePredicted) {
    return tf.losses.meanSquaredError(toBePredicted, predictions);
}

function train(predictors, toBePredicted, numIterations) {
    function computeLoss (predictors, toBePredicted) {
        let predictions = predict(predictors);
        return loss(predictions, toBePredicted);
    }
    let learningRate = 0.5; //suggested by Google Developers
    const OPTIMIZER = tf.train.sgd(learningRate); //suggested by Google Developers

    for (let iter = 0; iter < numIterations; iter++) {
        OPTIMIZER.minimize(computeLoss(predictors, toBePredicted));
    }
    return {
        a: lag.get(0),
        b: lag.get(1),
        c: lag.get(2),
        d: lag.get(3)
    };
};
//75 suggested by google developers
return train(predictors, toBePredicted, 75);
};
```

The problem is with minimze in the end as I said. The above code works fine and computes everything it is supposed to.

Thanks for any suggestions!
Chris

Comment: It turned out that the minimize function needs a predict function with trainable variables in the return. So all the model specifications should be implemented using tensor operations like .add(), .mul() directly in the return. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

`optimizer.minimize()` updates the weights during each cycle of training. For the weights to be updated, they need to be created using `tf.variable`. A variable created using `tf.variable` is mutable whereas tf.tensor creates immutable variable.

It is also noteworthy to point out that the predict() should return a function whose coefficient are created using tf.variable that will be updated to minimize the loss function.